# Adding widgets to form produced by model

Tags: python, django

Hey i am working on calendarium and it is layed out differently to what i normally work with so i'm having a little bit if trouble adding widgets to the form.

There is nothing in the EventCreatView so i dont understnad why there is a form on the page fully im guessing its the args that are passed.which is the one below

```
class EventMixin(object):
"""Mixin to handle event-related functions."""
model = Event
fields = '__all__'
}
```

i tried to add this:

```
class EventMixin(object):
"""Mixin to handle event-related functions."""
model = Event
fields = '__all__'
 widgets = {
  'start': model.DateTimeField(widget = AdminDateWidget)}


  @method_decorator(permission_required('calendarium.add_event'))
  def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(EventMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


class EventUpdateView(EventMixin, UpdateView):
"""View to update information of an event."""
pass


class EventCreateView(EventMixin, CreateView):
"""View to create an event."""
pass
```

i messed about with it and it didn't seem to work but i don't know if i'm doing the completely wrong thing.

Would love some help, thanks J

Comment: You'll need to give more information. What is this EventMixin actually mixed in to? Exactly where did you add that `widgets` dict?

Comment: I have no idea, its as new to you as it is to me, sorry i cant help much. i added the widgets to the EventMixin to see if it would work

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two issues here.

Firstly, `widgets` is an attribute on a form, not on a view. Like all editing views, UpdateView automatically creates a ModelForm for you based on the model if you don't specify one; but since you want to customise it, you need to define your ModelForm explicitly and use the `widgets` attribute in its Meta class.

Secondly, as the name implies, `widgets` sets the form's widgets, not its fields. In your case, you just need `widgets = {'start': AdminDateWidget}`.